# Built-in audio not working anymore Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Audio was working fine until a few days ago. I am not sure if a recent update broke it or if it was me trying to install some audio apps. I was looking to install an equalizer and installed these two apps: sudo apt install pulseaudio-equalizer, sudo apt install pavucontrol. I removed them later on. Audio is integrated in the motherboard (Gygabite GA-X99-Gaming G1 WIFI).

Audio from the graphics card works though, I can use an audio jack pass-through in my monitor when connected with HDMI. So at least it's not completely broken.

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` again and then poke around in there to see if anything's muted and/or set improperly to the wrong audio device/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it just started working again by itself.............